# How can I create a condtional WHERE clause that depends on the input values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, tokio-postgres

I am using the tokio_postgres crate with Rust.
Of course, I can create two seperate queries and perform condition checking on my input values in my code, although I am looking for a way to do it through the SQL query.

I am passing two values into my query
$1 = task_id,
$2 = user_uuid

My (pseduo) statement looks like this:

let statement =

```
SELECT status FROM assignments 
WHERE task_id = $1 OR user_uuid = $2;
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
db.query(&statement, &[&task_id, &user_uuid])
```

task_id: Option

user_uuid: Option

So, basically, task_id or user_uuid will always be null (or "None" in rust terms).

In my SQL query, how can I conditionally use one or the other, based on which one contains a value? So, if task_id is null, then the query will be

```
SELECT status FROM assignments 
user_uuid = $2;
```

Versus, if user_uuid is null, the query will be

```
SELECT status FROM assignments 
WHERE task_id = $1;
```

Should this simply be done in the Rust code? I feel like there is an easy way to do it with the SQL query though.

Comment: `where task_id = coalesce($1, task_id) and user_uuid = coalesce($2, user_uuid) and coalesce($1, $2) is not null`

Comment: `where case when task_id is not null then task_id = $1 when user_uuid is not null then user_uuid = $2 end;`